# Save 2 text, in the same file.csv but in two differenct columns on iMacros

Tags: macros, text-extraction, imacros

I'm working hard to understand how to save two different texts in a single file called file.csv (or .txt) but on two different columns.

I've build a `.JS` that generates random TEXTs, then fill some fields and then proceed with the rest of the macro.

What I want to do, is to save those TEXTs (email, password) in the .csv but in `{{!COL1}}` & `{{!COL2}}`

Is there any way to build something like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
set !extract value1
add !extract value2
saveas type=extract....
```